# Redirect 301 for tag doesn't work. How make?

Tags: .htaccess

It is necessary to make a redirect 
 from https://example.com/blog/tag/sometag 
 to https://example.com/tag/sometag

I try to use

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^blog/tag/(.*)$ tag/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but nothing happens

Comment: Are there other rewrite rules that can interfere with this one? Have you tested if your .htaccess file is taken in consideration at all?

Comment: I try use `Redirect 301 /blog/tag/tag1/ https://example.com/tag/tag1/` and it works

Comment: Ok so your file is taken in consideration, what about other rewrite rules in the file/parent folders .htaccess files (if there are some)?

Comment: No. Only 5G/6G firewall/blacklist

Comment: Remove all that “firewall” stuff, and test with a .htaccess that contains _only_ what you have shown above. Any difference?